# Keeping a subheading with its first line of text in an epub

Tags: epub, css

I'm converting an InDesign document to Epub.  I'm using Microsoft Edge as the epub reader (that might be a mistake...).  Edge is open in an approximately 1280x1024 window and is showing two "pages" of text at a time.  Rolling the mouse button "turns pages."

My problem occurs with this turn-page context that Edge is using.  Rather than simply scrolling through an entire chapter, it's imposing the context of a book.  Consequently, a subheader may appear on the last line of the right-hand "page" with its associated text block on the next page.

```
My Subheader
Lorem ipsum...
```

becomes

```
My Subheader
```

And then you turn the "page" to find

`Lorem ipsum...`

From [this question](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1235/keeping-lines-together-in-epub) I learned about `page-break-inside: avoid;` and `page-break-before: always;`, but those appear to be block-level CSS attributes, forcing me to decide with how much of the following text the subheader must be grouped.  E.G.,

```
<div style="page-break-inside: avoid;"><p class="subhead-01">My Subheader</p>
<p class="normal">Lorem ipsum</div>...</p>
```

Now, I know I'm wishing for world peace, but is there a CSS attribute I would assign to the subheader block that affectively means, "keep this block with the first line of the next block"?  Something along the lines of:

```
<p class="subhead-01" style="keep-with: next-line;">My Subheader</p>
<p class="normal">Lorem ipsum...</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`page-break-after: avoid` should work, if the reading system supports it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
Create a new div

CSS

```
div.Heading-Block {
  display: block;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="Heading-Block">
      <p class="Heading-2">Your subheader</p>
      <p class="BodyText">Your paragraph</p>
</div>
```